# randint in Python 3.5 doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am a new to Python, and I ran into some issues when developing a *D&D Dice* program.

```
import random   

print("Hi,here you can roll all D´n´D Dice´s!")  
dice=input("What dice do u want?D4,D6,D8,D10,D12,D20 or D100?")  

if dice=="D4" or "d4":  
    print(random.randint(1,4))  
elif dice=="D6" or "d6":  
    print(random.randint(1,6))  
elif dice=="D8" or "d8":  
    print(random.randint(1,8))  
elif dice=="D10"or"d10":  
    print(random.randint(1,10))  
elif dice=="D12"or"d12":  
    print(random.randint(1,12))      
elif dice=="D20"or"d20":  
    print(random.randint(1,20))  
elif dice=="D100"or"d100":  
    print(random.randint(1,100))  
else: print("No?Ok!")
```

When I run the program and enter the number of dice, it always enter the first `if` statement.

Comment: Do you always get a number from 1 to 4 (as Baruchel's answer fixes), or do you always get the number 1? Also, what do you get if you enter invalid input (for example, `D3`?)

Answer (score 3):

You want to write:

```
if dice=="D4" or dice=="d4":
```

instead of:

```
if dice=="D4" or "d4":
```

`"d4"` by itself has a (true) boolean value because it isn't an empty string.

Comment: Or `dice.lower() == 'd4'`